# Android: UI code written inside Async functions not working in BillingClient version 4.0.0

Tags: android, asynchronous, billingclient

Recently I upgraded to Android BillingClient version 4.0.0 from 3.0.2.
I am facing 2 issues in Async functions. The UI code written inside Async functions like showing AlertDialog and disabling button is not working.
Showing AlertDialog inside billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() is not working in billingclient version 4.0.0. This was working fine in version 3.0.2.
Similarly disabling a button inside billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync() is not working in billingclient version 4.0.0.

The code is given below.
Please guide me how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
public class SubscribeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    PurchasesUpdatedListener, BillingClientStateListener,
    AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener {

private Button btnSubscribe;
private BillingClient billingClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subscribe);

    btnSubscribe = findViewById(R.id.btnSubscribe);
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this)
            .enablePendingPurchases().build();
}

private void generatePurchaseDetails() {

        billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS,
                (billingResult, purchaseList) -> {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    // some more code here...
                    builder.create().show();
                    // This AlertDialog is not getting displayed in billingclient version 4.0.0. This was working fine in version 3.0.2.
        });
}

private void queryPurchases() {

    billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS,
            (billingResult, purchases) -> {
          
          // The below line is not getting executed properly in billingclient 4.0.0.
          btnSubscribe.setEnabled(false);
          // some more code here...The control does not come to these lines of code.
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same issue and figured out that billingclient 4 is using background threads instead of UI threads on callbacks. So you have to run your code which updates UI in a UI thread.

```
private void queryPurchases() {

  billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS,
    (billingResult, purchases) -> {

      activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            // The below line is not getting executed properly in billingclient 4.0.0.
            btnSubscribe.setEnabled(false);
            // some more code here...The control does not come to these lines of code.
          }
        }
      });

  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I was not aware that background thread was used. I used 2 activities (pages) to solve the problem. I have not tried your solution since I already solved it by using 2 activities. Your solution may help others.